# svn bugtraq copies properties to branches

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using Tortoise SVN 1.75 and have a properties applies on our trunk code to enforce entry of the bug tracking number that committed changes are related to. This is done using the [BUGTRAQ](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html) properties.

While I want this behaviour on trunk, I don't want it on branches. The issue is that when someone branches from trunk, the properties are copied to the branch as well.

Is there a way of preventing properties being copied when branching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all these properties are permanent (in terms of "they don't disappear automagically") properties of object, which you copy. But they are *versioned properties*, which you can change|remove **in branch**

Comment: I thought as much but it didn't hurt to ask. Thanks